# if statement condition is triggering regardless of wether or not condition is met

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, conditional-statements, execute

This if statement triggers regardless of the values in the condition , i substituted number for explanation sake. Why is the condition triggering the execution regardless if the condition is true or not. Ive tried every scenario but the execution in the statement triggers every time .

```
if(1 != 1 && 1 != 2 ){
execute code
exit();
 }
```

here is the exact code:

```
if($name1 != $winner && $name2 != $winner ){
echo " The player you chose as winner is not associated with match id: $match_id ";
exit();
}
```

Comment: No, it's not true - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a227c5ddd20c3e331bbed7a1c042438a3d4fc880

Comment: correct, the statement is not true, but in my scenario it executes the code

Comment: Either the condition is true, or the same code exists somewhere else as well. (Barring crazy things like a goto that jumps into the block.) Did you actually try to replace the condition with ```if(false)``` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for the condition mentioned in the post to return `true`.

However what you are saying may happen if you write code something like below:

```
if(1 != 1 && 1 != 2 );{
    echo 'case 1';
}
```

Note the `;` after the if(). Are you sure your code does not have the semi-colon after the if()? If you have mistakenly placed a `;` then the if statement is evaluated as a single line statement and the code within the if-block is considered by the interpreter as **outside** of the if condition.

**Edit based on the updated question**

Please check the following:

1. `$winner` is correctly set to either of `$name1` or `$name2`.
2. Verify that variable declaration scope for `$winner` is correct - it has been some time since I have done PHP but this is possibly something else to look out for.

Other than these I do not see any other reason why this code should behave the way you state.

Comment: im certain there are no semi colons after the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Just maybe ... Have a very close look at the values of the four variables involved.

Comparisons using != can give some surprising results.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). EDIT: Links fixed

Even if that doesn't solve this problem, better to try to use !== wherever possible.